# npm installation of jsreport is failing

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm

I am not sure what is to blame here. Is it npm having a problem or a specific package that is corrupted or something?

I am trying to install JSReport on an Azure Ubuntu VM and have followed the simple instructions here (http://jsreport.net/downloads/). However, when I run the `sudo npm install jsreport --production` I get this error from npm:

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/sntp
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/boom
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/sntp
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/hoek
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cryptiles
npm WARN engine boom@2.10.1: wanted: {"node":">=0.10.40"} (current: {"node":"v0.10.25","npm":"1.3.10"})
npm WARN engine hoek@2.16.3: wanted: {"node":">=0.10.40"} (current: {"node":"v0.10.25","npm":"1.3.10"})
npm WARN engine cryptiles@2.0.5: wanted: {"node":">=0.10.40"} (current: {"node":"v0.10.25","npm":"1.3.10"})
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/weak-map/1.0.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/weak-map/1.0.0
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/<username>/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

And of course... when I look for `/home/<username>/npm-debug.log` there is no file at all. I have tried deleting the `node_modules` twice now and retrying without any luck. Any ideas?

Comment: So... if I leave out the "--production" flag when installing jsreport it works just fine. What are the consequences of doing so? Can I add it after the fact so I can run it as a production instance still?

Answer (score 1):

You need to upgrade your version of node. It seems you currently have v0.10.25 installed, but some packages need/want at least v0.10.40. As far as the node v0.10 branch goes, v0.10.43 is the latest as of this writing. The latest node LTS release is v4.4.0 and latest stable node release is v5.9.0.

Answer (score 0):

Extending correct @mscdex answer with updated jsreport ubuntu installation guide: https://github.com/jsreport/docs/blob/master/installation/ubuntu.md

> Official ubuntu apt-get distribution contains outdated node.js. I
>   prefer to use [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) to manage my node.js installation.
>
> ```
> wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.31.0/install.sh | bash
> ```
>
> If you are using terminal like putty, you cannot pipe the installation
>   to the bash, so you need to save it to file and run it. Afterwards you
>   need to reopen the terminal.
>
> ```
> wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.31.0/install.sh > install.sh
> chmod +x install.sh
> ./install.sh
> ```
>
> Now install node.js
>
> ```
> nvm install 5
> ```
>
> To be able to sudo run the npm or node you need to also run the
>   following command
>
> ```
> n=$(which node);n=${n%/bin/node}; chmod -R 755 $n/bin/*; sudo cp -r $n/{bin,lib,share} /usr/local
> ```

Afterwards you should be able to run

```
sudo npm install jsreport --production
```